# Не получается передать переменную из php в js

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php

class Comment
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        /*
        /   Конструктор
        */

        $this->data = $row;
    }

    public function markup()
    {
        /*
        /   Данный метод выводит разметку XHTML для комментария
        */

        // Устанавливаем псевдоним, чтобы не писать каждый раз $this->data:
        $d = &$this->data;

        $link_open = '';
        $link_close = '';

        if($d['url']){

            // Если был введн URL при добавлении комментария,
            // определяем открывающий и закрывающий теги ссылки

            $link_open = '<a href="'.$d['url'].'">';
            $link_close =  '</a>';
        }

        // Преобразуем время в формат UNIX:
        $d['dt'] = strtotime($d['dt']);

        // Нужно для установки изображения по умолчанию:
        $url = 'http://'.dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'/img/default_avatar.gif';
        global $email;
        $id_comment = $d['id'];
        if($email == $d['email']){$delete_comment = '<div onClick="deleteComent(!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!///здесь нужно передать переменную - $id_comment///!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)" style="position:absolute; cursor:pointer; margin-left:480px; margin-top:-13px;"><img src="images/delete_comment.png" onmouseover=\'this.src="images/delete_comment2.png";\' 
onmouseout=\'this.src="images/delete_comment.png";\'></div>';}
        return '

            <div class="comment">
                <div class="avatar">

                    '.$link_open.'
                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($d['email']).'?size=50&amp;default='.urlencode($url).'" />
                    '.$link_close.'
                    <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y A',$d['dt']).'">'.date('H:i \o\n d M Y A',$d['dt']).'</div>
                </div>
                <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
                <div id="del_com">'.$delete_comment.'</div>
                <div class="text">'.$d['body'].'</div>
            </div>
        ';
    }

    public static function validate(&$arr)
    {
        /*
        /   Данный метод используется для проверки данных отправляемых через AJAX.
        /
        /   Он возвращает true/false в зависимости от правильности данных, и наполняет
        /   массив $arr, который преается как параметр либо данными либо сообщением об ошибке.
        */

        $errors = array();
        $data   = array();

        // Используем функцию filter_input, введенную в PHP 5.2.0

        if(!($data['email'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
        {
            $errors['email'] = 'Пожалуйста, введите правильный Email.';
        }

        if(!($data['url'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'url',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)))
        {
            // Если в поле URL был введн неправильный URL,
            // действуем так, как будто URL не был введен:

            $url = '';
        }

        // Используем фильтр с возвратной функцией:

        if(!($data['body'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'body',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
        {
            $errors['body'] = 'Please enter the text of your comment.';

        }
           if (strlen($data['body'])<10) {$errors['body'] = 'Sorry, but you can not send the message,<br> because it is less than 10 characters';}

        if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
        {
            $errors['name'] = 'Пожалуйста, введите имя.';
        }

        if(!empty($errors)){

            // Если есть ошибки, копируем массив $errors в $arr:

            $arr = $errors;
            return false;
        }

        // Если данные введены правильно, подчищаем данные и копируем их в $arr:

        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
        }

        // email дожен быть в нижнем регистре:

        $arr['email'] = strtolower(trim($arr['email']));

        return true;

    }

    private static function validate_text($str)
    {
        /*
        /   Данный метод используется как FILTER_CALLBACK
        */

        if(mb_strlen($str,'cp1251')<1)
            return false;

        // Кодируем все специальные символы html (<, >, ", & .. etc) и преобразуем
        // символ новой строки в тег <br>:

        // Удаляем все оставщиеся символы новой строки
        $str = str_replace(array(chr(10),chr(13)),'',$str);

        return $str;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<div onClick="deleteComent(' . $id_comment . '" style="
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно я не буду смотреть в ваш код? =)
Чтобы передать переменную из php в js, особых хлопот не возникает, если только передача не осуществляется в обработчике события. PHP - серверный язык, а поэтому выполняется один раз - после обновления страницы. Так, что помните это...а так, передать переменную из php в js
можно так:

```
<?php $a=1;

echo("<script>
var b=".$a."
</script>");

?>
```